# dashed line in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to set the linetype of my legend.

My data is like:

```
  VisitMonth VisitYear CaixaForum MNAC   FirstDay
  1:         01      2007         NA 7125 2007-01-01
  2:         02      2007         NA 5345 2007-02-01
  3:         03      2007         NA 4996 2007-03-01
  4:         04      2007         NA 5476 2007-04-01
  5:         05      2007         NA 6160 2007-05-01
 ---                                                
 98:         02      2015      17903 2360 2015-02-01
 99:         03      2015      30400 2930 2015-03-01
100:         04      2015      25422 3088 2015-04-01
101:         05      2015      10787 2130 2015-05-01
102:         06      2015       3679 2047 2015-06-01
```

I want to plot the time serie of CaixaForum and MNAC column. I have code the following:

```
ggplot(data = MUSEUMS, aes(x = FirstDay, y = MNAC)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.75, aes(x = FirstDay, y = MNAC, colour = "MNAC")) + 
  geom_line(size=0.75, aes(y = CaixaForum, colour = "CaixaForum"), linetype = "dashed") + 
  labs(title = "", x = "", y = "Monthly Visitors") +  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold"),  legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.position=c(0.5, 1.05), text = element_text(size=20)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend",values=c(MNAC="black", CaixaForum="black"))
```

As you can observe, you can not distinguish between the two linetypes in the legend:

[image]

How can I fixed?

I coded other answers in stackoverflow but they haven't worked.

Comment: You can use `melt` from the `reshape2` package to convert your data into the long format. You would get two columns `variable` and `value`. You then change your aesthetics to `y=value` and `linetype=variable`.

Comment: @drmariod ...probably you meant `linetype = variable` as well, if they want that in the legend too, which they appear to.

Comment: The bigger picture that you're missing is that things appear in the legend when you _map_ aesthetics to a variable in your data inside of `aes()`.

Comment: Yes, I was focused on color, not on linetype... changed it now and provided an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just switch to using `linetype` instead of `color` in the two point layers, as you're not actually using `color` for anything in your graphic.

It would look like this:

```
ggplot(data = MUSEUMS, aes(x = FirstDay, y = MNAC)) + 
    geom_line(size=0.75, aes(x = FirstDay, y = MNAC, linetype = "MNAC")) + 
    geom_line(size=0.75, aes(y = CaixaForum, linetype = "CaixaForum")) + 
    labs(title = "", x = "", y = "Monthly Visitors") +  theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold"),  legend.direction = "horizontal",
            legend.position=c(0.5, 1.05), text = element_text(size=20)) + 
    scale_linetype_manual(name="Legend",values=c(MNAC="solid", CaixaForum="dashed"))
```

If you really wanted to use the approach you are using now for some reason, you could get the lines you want via `override.aes` in `guide_legend` by adding the following line to your graphic:

```
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("solid", "dashed"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I think it has to do with the legend line being too small to show the dashes. Adding:

```
theme(legend.key.size=unit(3,"lines"))
```

fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I created some random data to demonstrate the solution...

```
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10), b=rnorm(10), x=1:10, other_data=rnorm(10))
mdf <- melt(df, id.vars='x', measure.vars=c('a','b'))
ggplot(mdf, aes(x, value, linetype=variable)) + geom_line()
```